# Making continuous variables into 2 factors based on value for multiple columns in R

Tags: r, cut

I have a data frame with 40+ columns. I want to do something pretty simple that I thought cut could do: Change all my values into 2 factors, those <10 and those >10 as "0" or "1" for columns 3:38.  I tried using cut, but I get errors:

```
'data.frame':   182 obs. of  38 variables:
 $ col_names                           : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Case_control                        : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Sample_1_fung               : int  0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

I tried

```
test_cat <- lapply(qpcr180_df[,3:38],cut, breaks=2,by=10, quantile=F)
Error in cut.default(X[[20L]], ...) : 'breaks' are not unique
>
```

and: when I do `test_cat <- lapply(qpcr180_df[,3:38],cut, breaks=2*(-1:9), quantile=F, labels=2*(0:9))`

I get a table that has the factors labeled but from 2-12 and NA rather than one label for `<10` and one for `>10`.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
set.seed(42)
dat1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20,5*4, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
dat2 <- dat1
dat2[] <- cut(as.matrix(dat1),breaks=c(-Inf,10,Inf),labels=c('0','1'))
dat2
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  1  1  1  1  1
#2  1  1  1  0  0
#3  0  1  0  0  0
#4  1  0  1  1  1

dat1
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1 19 13 14 19 20
#2 19 11 15  6  3
#3  6 15 10 10 10
#4 17  3 15 19 12
```